# No me registran los datos con volley metodo GET

Tags: android-volley

Estoy con un proyecto para mi tesis que incluye aplicación android, en el cual el usuario se conecta y después realiza una captura de codigo QR cuya respuesta mas el id del usuario debo registrar en la base de datos.
Lo he hecho con android studio y utilizando la libreria volley para las conexiones. Con el loguin todo bien, pero con el registro tengo inconvenientes ya que me dice que se registra correctamente pero no recibe en la base de datos, alguna ayuda?
No tengo mucha experiencia programando y lo que hice lo logré investigando.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
 btguardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Registro("http://192.168.0.4/Tesis_asistencia/registro.php?id="+tvidasignatura.getText()+"&scanContent="+tvidprofesor.getText());

        }
    });

private void Registro(String URL) {

    Log.i("url",""+URL);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se ha registrado correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ja = new JSONArray(response);
                String contra = ja.getString(3);
                String nom = ja.getString(1);
                String mat = ja.getString(2);
                String fec = ja.getString(0);

                tvnom.setText(nom);
                tvmateria.setText(mat);
                tvfecha.setText(fec);

                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

         }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {

             }
         });

        queue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Mi php de registro esta comprobado que registra los datos:

```
<?php

//ESTABLECEMOS LA CONEXION
include('functions.php'); 

    //TOMAMOS LOS DATOS ENVIADOS DESDE LA APLICACION
    $alumno=$_GET['id'];
    $profesor=$_GET['scanContent'];




    //SEPARAMOS LA CADENA DE DATOS DEL CODIGO QR
    $datos=explode("/",$profesor);
    $d1=$datos[0];
    $d2=$datos[1];
    $d3=$datos[2];

    //EJECUTAMOS EL REGISTRO DE LOS DATOS
    $insert=ejecutarSQLcommand("INSERT INTO asistencia(id_alumno,asis_alumno,observacion,fecha,id_profesor,id_asignatura,asis_profesor)VALUES('$alumno','1','','$d3','$d1','$d2','1')");


    if ($resultset = getSQLResultSet("SELECT * FROM asistencia WHERE fecha='$d3' and id_alumno=$alumno")) {

        while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        echo json_encode($row);


        }

   }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas a todos
Me causa gracia el responder mi propia pregunta, pero gracias a los que visitaron e intentaron.
Mi problema estaba en el parámetro que enviaba como cadena desde la aplicación y lo que recibía mi WS PHP.

//SEPARAMOS LA CADENA DE DATOS DEL CODIGO QR
    $datos=explode("/",$profesor);
    $d1=$datos[0];
    $d2=$datos[1];
    $d3=$datos[2];

Como verán, en el explode utilizo "/"como separador cuando reciba el parámetro, pero estaba enviando "|" por lo que me informaba en la aplicación que si registraba, pero en realidad no llegaba a la base de datos.
Ya de paso les dejo especialmente para los principiantes como yo, la forma en que hice un registro con la librería volley método get.

Saludos!

Comment: responder a tu propia pregunta es totalmente válido; lo que te menciono que te faltaría es: darle formato al código; elige lo y después dale clic al icono `{}` así se verá formateado, después acéptala dando clic en la palomita que esta del lado izquierdo; así servirá para otros usuarios como referencia y recibes votos positivos saludos